# How would I go about converting a function that uses fetch calls to async/await?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

How would I go about converting this to use async/await instead of fetch? Sorry, I'm really confused on the subject and would really appreciate some help.

```
coreHTTP.prototype.post = (url, data) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fetch(url, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {"content-type": "application/json"},
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => resolve(data))
      .catch(err => reject(err));
  });
}
```

Comment: convert... what?  the `prototype.post`?

Answer (score 0):

How bout leaving the fetch as it is? If you just want to use awaits than there's no problem with it being there.

```js
coreHTTP.prototype.post = async (url, data) => {
    const responseData = await fetch(url, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {"content-type": "application/json"},
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    });

    const responseJson = await responseData.json();
    return responseJson;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try to remember it like this. JS uses asynchronous coding right, so we do that using promises. One way is as you see it in your question where you call for a resource(fetch in this case) and we wait for the resource modification using `.then` and `.catch` .

Similarly, for async/await the logic is the same except syntax is a bit different. First of all to use await inside any function we have to first define the function as `async` and then you just use await ahead of any function you use inside that. You can also use try/catch to deal with errors better. Let me know if you need help understanding more.
I am new to this comments section so I dont know how to exactly attach code snippets but I will attach a screenshot for now for your reference.

[image: Async/await]

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.